# Having trouble trying to upload images on instagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, shutil, pathlib

first I'm sorry for my english!!I have a problem with my code because I want it to automatically upload an image to my Instagram profile but it doesn't work because it repeats the same photo over and over but I don't want that to happen!!Can someone help me please?? (the code take the pictures from a folder and choose them randomly

```
import random
from instabot import Bot
import os, glob
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


cookie_del = glob.glob("config/*cookie.json")
os.remove(cookie_del[0])


bot = Bot()

sent_photos = []


def upload(path):
    bot.login(username= '', password='')
    bot.upload_photo(path, caption=' ')
    sent_photos.append(path)


while True:
    group_of_items = os.listdir("C:/Users/user/Desktop/teste/PICS")
    num_selet = 1
    list_of_random = random.sample(group_of_items, num_selet)
    first_random = list_of_random[0]
    path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/teste/PICS/" + str(first_random)
    if path in sent_photos:
        continue
    else:
       upload(path)
```

Comment: Why not just do `first_random = random.choice(group_of_items)`? Does that fix it?

Comment: Every time you run this script sent_photos will be reset so duplicate files will be uploaded. Is this what you mean— could you clarify "it repeats the same photo over and over".

Comment: @RandomDavis yes!! thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the indentation for `sent_photos.append(path)` in upload function is incorrect, which would explain why same photos are being uploaded again.
Just fix that and then the problem should be fixed.

Comment: I dind't understand very well what you said, please can you show me how I can do that?

Comment: You edited your answer to include the correct indentation, it should work now